# High Sierra Installation com.apple.osinstall error -3

Tags: hard-drive, high-sierra, crash

My mac book pro 2010 started acting up last night.  Wifi was slow and certain letters were not displayed properly. I restarted the computer and it failed to boot up again.

I took the drive from the bad computer and put it in a working mac book pro 2013.  The computer had issues booting up initially.  After restarting the NVRAM by holding command + option + p + r, I can now access the recovery screen. I tried selecting the start up disk. I get the following error message, "you cant change the startup disk to the selected disk running bless to place boot files failed".

I tried to reinstall high sierra, but I get a com.apple.osinstall error -3 error after restart.  What should I try next to troubleshoot the issue?